# How do I find Metrics to Support the Evaluation of Association Rule?

Tags: r, associations, rules, business-rules, market-basket-analysis

I have applied Association rules to a dataset of an online store (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail#). I have gotten 4rules (Rules A,B,C y D). When checking the time series of each item of each rule(Graph is shown the months on x-axis and the amount of sales for each item on y-axis).

If for example the Rule A has, item 1 and item 2, and the sales along the months of these two items follow the same pattern. Would this be enough to think I have found a good rule? If no, which method I can use to evaluate the Association rules? (Any academic paper would be very useful)

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you want us to do your searching on metrics for arules.

Comment: Not really, @42- sorry if you got that impression. I have done my own approach here, I would like to share it with you and I would appreciate your experienced insights:

Comment: The graph sales/month for each item show very similar patterns along the year, with March as the month where item 1 and 2 are more sold. To find out if apart from correlation, it exists association between Items 1 and 2(They are bought together), I have printed separately sorting by the March and by item getting two outcomes. Both of them show that mainly they share the the same "InvoiceNo"s, so they would have been sold within the same bill. 
Would this be a way that for this rule, correlation implies association, so this items were often bought together?

Comment: > March <- data[data$Month == "03",]
March21094 <- March[March$StockCode == "21094",]
March21094
nrow(March21094)
March21086 <- March[March$StockCode == "21086",]
March21086